# Native Extensions fails to build for various gems

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ubuntu, rubygems, rvm

I'm working on Ubuntu platform with different versions of Ruby and Rails. I use RVM for version control.

Each time I create a new project or do bundle install for a new project, I always get `Failed to build native extensions for ...` for various gems at one go.

However, when I install these gems individually, i get no issues at all.

I've been doing this for quite some time now but its starting to get annoying. I can't run the individual installation for each gem.

Also, once i install each gem, i run `bundle install` just to be sure. Everything runs file until i use some rake or rails command like `rake db:create` and get the following error

`rake aborted!
LoadError: incompatible library version - /home/***/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.1@admin/gems/bcrypt-3.1.11/lib/bcrypt_ext.so`

I then move forward with solving this error.

Can you please help me understand the issue and resolve it. I'm sorry if the explaination is obvious but this is something i fail to understand each time i try to.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: This should solve your issue. https://github.com/bundler/bundler/issues/2648

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that some gems require some system-level libraries to be installed. For instance, the `nokogiri` gem requries `ruby-dev`, `zlib1g-dev`, and `liblzma-dev` to be installed on Ubuntu as stated on their [website](http://www.nokogiri.org/tutorials/installing_nokogiri.html).

Bundler does not tell you what system-level libraries are required to build native extensions so you have to search for and install those yourself.

I have written a gem that helps with this issue, you could also check it out: **[rsyslibs](https://github.com/amrrbakry/rsyslibs)**